# Why postgresql creates force subtransactions in large statement except sql commands (savepoint...)?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I performed following large transaction without any sub transactions:

```
begin
for i in 1..10000000 loop
INSERT INTO src.customers
(id, first_name, last_name, email)
values
(i,'First Name', 'Last Name', 'somemail@gmail.com');
end loop;
end;
```

Sometimes, not always, I've seen that postgresql wrote this big one transaction as a one transaction with many subtransaction into wal file:

```
rmgr: Transaction len (rec/tot): 168000073/168000073, tx: 2884083787, lsn: C1/C486C9B8, prev C1/C486C870, desc: COMMIT 2024-01-17 12:43:35.646805 UTC; subxacts: 2884083788 2884083791 <many of them>
```

But I expected only one transaction without any subtrancations in wal file. Statement does not have any savepoint or exception clause...
I have not found any information about creating force subtransactions.
Do you know why postgresql creates force subtransactions in large sql statement except sql commands (savepoint...)?

Comment: [I already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77858638/6464308) that this piece of code will never create subtransactions. Your actual code must be different. Or do you have any weird extensions activated?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, but my tester found it... I've written that it happens sometime, when database is busy. She found this kind of behavior in simple 15.5 version and in pro version. Wal file does not lie. my boss requires me to find a cause of it... We cannot say or pretend that it cannot be happen, if it really happens. I will analyze that. If I will have any changes about, I will notify here. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any extensions installed that might do something weird? Abominations like [pg_statement_rollback](https://github.com/lzlabs/pg_statement_rollback)? Or, if you are running different code than what you show, are you using the JDBC driver with `autosave=always`?

Comment: Is your 'tester' a person, or a piece of software?  If the latter, can you share it with us?  At a minimum, you should provide a runnable case, which that is not.  It needs to be wrapped into a function, or a procedure, or a DO block.  And you should show or describe how transaction are started and ended, how much concurrency is needed to trigger it, and about what fraction of the time it happens.